# how to get a cumulative data? I am trying to get the below bucketing in SQL, but not getting desired result/pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, hue

So that <30 bucket vales are not being shown in <60 and so on. how can I achieve this

```
    case when DATEDIFF((to_date('2022-01-07', 'yyyy-MM-dd')),max(to_date((column), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) between 0 and 29 then '<30' 
        when DATEDIFF((to_date('2022-01-07', 'yyyy-MM-dd')),max(to_date((column), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) between 0 and 59 then '<60'
        when DATEDIFF((to_date('2022-01-07', 'yyyy-MM-dd')),max(to_date((column), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) between 0 and 89 then '<90' 
        when DATEDIFF((to_date('2022-01-07', 'yyyy-MM-dd')),max(to_date((column), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) between 0 and 179 then '<180' 
        when DATEDIFF((to_date('2022-01-07', 'yyyy-MM-dd')),max(to_date((column), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) > 180 then '>180'
     end 
     else 'bad_date'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your between conditions

```
... between 0 and 29 then '<30'
... between 30 and 59 then '<60'
... between 60 and 89 then '<90'
... between 90 and 179 then '<180'
... > 180 then '>180'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but I need first bucket to have 0-29 second bucket should have values between 0-59 and like wise till < 180 the below buckets should add up, that is what I am trying to acheive

Comment: Can you show your sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sure, actually I have posted it in answers sections, since it's not allowing to post the picture